# VB6 Service debugging with WINDBG

Tags: debugging, service, vb6, windbg

First and foremost, I'm an absolute newbie at debugging compiled code (until recently, I didn't even know it was possible!). I've successfully used the VC6 IDE to attach to a process but I can't get WinDbg to work...

The problem is that I have a VB6 service that I need to debug in a production server. I really don't understand much of how the .EXE is compiled because it is generated by an external tool called "NT Service Toolkit". The code I have is compiled into an ActiveX DLL that is used by this .EXE.

I've done everything I found on the internet to make the service debuggable with the VC6 IDE: compile without optimizations and generate symbols. When I use the VC6 IDE to attach to it, it works as expected... I can set breakpoints and everything works fine except for the annoying bug that kills the service when the debugging session stops.

When I try to use WinDbg however, I cannot set breakpoints; it fails with an error:

```
Unable to insert breakpoint 0 at 00000000`0046f715, Win32 error 0n299
    "Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed."
bp0 at 00000000`0046f715 failed
WaitForEvent failed
```

I've already downloaded symbols for windows' components from the symbol servers, as instructed in the documentation I could find, and I also included the PDB file for my service in the symbols folder...

One thing I noted is that I can get symbolic information when I check the "Noninvasive" box when selecting the process to attach to because I see things like `wow64win!ZwUserGetMessage` instead of just the *address`offset* syntax... but when I do, I also get this warning:

```
WARNING: Process <PID> is not attached as a debuggee
     The process can be examined but debug events will not be received
```

In this case, I can set breakpoints, but when I try to run the service, it fails with:

```
0:000> g
   ^ No runnable debuggees error in 'g'
```

**UPDATE**

When I set a breakpoint in "Noninvasive" mode, detach, and reattach with "Noninvasive" un-checked, the breakpoints I set while in "Noninvasive" mode remain, and are hit successfully, but I can't set new breakpoints unless I repeat the whole process (detach, attach in "Noninvasive" mode and reattach). Does this make sense? What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: The output shows that you have used a 64 bits Windbg version. 
I believe that VC6 only can produce 32 buts binaries, so check the bitness of your process, and if 32 bits, use a 32 bits Windbg(x86).

Comment: Could you be specific regarding VB6 (Visual Basic) or VC6 (Visual C++)?

Comment: @KjellGunnar downloaded the x86 version, and tried it... the inserting of new breakpoints still fails...

Comment: @ThomasW. Sorry about that... The code is compiled in VB6. I just made the mention of VC6 because its IDE allows you to attach to a running process, where the VB6 IDE doesn't...

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. It was a conflict in the module names.

When WinDbg loads the modules for a process, it names them as the file where they live, just WITHOUT extension. Therefore, if, as in my case, two modules that must be loaded share the same name, say `MyService.exe` and `MyService.dll`, there will be two modules named MyService; in this case, WinDbg breaks the ambiguity by appending _<*start-address*> to the name, resulting in, for example:

```
...
MyService
MyService_11000000
...
```

*(The following is a rationalization of what happened, since like I said, I'm pretty new to "attach to process"-type debugging and I lack knowledge of WinDbg internals...)*

My problem was that the PDB file for the DLL (MyService.pdb), which was the module I was interested in debugging, was being matched to the EXE file's module (MyService), so the DLL's symbols were not loaded before trying to "restore" the breakpoints, resulting in the `Win32 error 0n299` I was seeing earlier... It appears that the `g` command also tries to "set" the saved breakpoints, and since the symbols were not yet loaded, it would not let me start the thing after the default breakpoint either...

...

Or something like that... Obviously, if someone has a more accurate explanation, I'd very much like to be enlightened. :)

For the moment, I just changed the service EXE's name, and now everything works fine.